# react - adding item to array in state at a specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an app im building in reactjs and react native. I have an array in my state that I'm adding image uri's to.

```
state = {
  images: []
}
```

The problem lies in that I want to add images uris to this array at a specific  index like this

```js
//pass the index I want the image uri assigned to

pickImage = (imageIndex) => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
  });

  if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({images[imageIndex]: result.uri})
  }

}
```

however, the above doesn't work, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: It actually throws a syntax error with unexpected token ,

Comment: @juicy89 Yes `{images[imageIndex]: result.uri}` is not a valid object literal.

Comment: Both your answers worked perfectly as expected. Without sounding ridiculous, is one preferred over the other in a general sense? I only ask as I'm still relatively new to JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to modify state somewhat directly. Try this instead:

```
pickImage = (imageIndex) => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
  });

  const images = { ...this.state };
  images[imageIndex] = result.uri;

  if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ images })
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const { images } = prevState;
  images.splice(imageIndex, 0, result.uri);
  return images;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A new array should be created with a different value in that index. We want to make a new array because [it is an antipattern to mutate state.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) The new array can be created by making a copy of this.state.images and modifying the value at the specific index.

```
const copyOfImages = [...this.state.images];
copyOfImages[imageIndex] = newValue;
this.setState({images: copyOfImages});
```

Array.prototype.map can be leveraged to make this code a bit more functional.

```
this.setState(previousState => ({
  images: previousState.images.map(
    (image, index) => index === imageIndex ? result.uri : image
  );
});
```